# HTML DIV or SPAN tag for "more..." when taller than 1 line

Tags: html, css

Is there a `div` or a `span` tag or CSS that will show a "more..." if the text between is taller than 1 line and then allow you to click on the more... to expand to show all?  I have a row of icons with a paragraph under each that I need to only display one row of text (which will vary based on the browser width).

Comment: What have you tried, where is your code? please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There is actually AFAIK

Comment: There's CSS:  `overflow:elispsis` which seems to do what you want

Comment: @krowe2 f*ck the users on this site? Pourquoi? :-/

Comment: Can you update your question with some code and an example of what you're trying to reach and what has not worked for you so far? Cheers

Comment: Nope , I tried to do it *kinda* with `:target` but I was wrong it didn't work

Comment: Worked with `checkbox` and `:checekd` though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done -*not very practical though as it needs to be handled properly, also the "show More" will be below the text block*- by making use of the `:checked` for the `checkbox`, but the `checkbox` has to be before the paragraph we want to control it's height, giving the `checkbox` `display:none` and make the `label` for it as the toggling controller, just like this:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9t3yL97h/2/)

```css
.para{
  max-height:20px;
  overflow:hidden; /* needed to hide the rest of the content */
  transition:all 1s;
}
.chk{
  display:none; /* hide the checkbox */
}

/* if the checkboxed is checked, we show the following .para div by
   increasing the max height property 
*/
.chk:checked ~ .para{
  max-height:500px;
  transition:all 1s;
}

/* change the text to "Show Less" if the full text is shown */
.chk:checked ~ .lbl::after{
  content:'Show Less';
}
.lbl{
  color:blue;
  text-decoration:underline;
  cursor:pointer;
}

/* by default the text is "Show More" as long as the checkbox is not checked*/
.lbl::after{
  content:'Show More';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkbx1" class="chk">
  <div class="para">
    Fruitcake toffee oat cake cheesecake chocolate sesame snaps. Cookie topping pie powder croissant gummies. Biscuit gingerbread toffee chocolate cake cupcake. Sesame snaps marzipan pudding chupa chups candy croissant chocolate dragée. Jelly-o bonbon gummies jelly ice cream tiramisu bonbon. Cake candy apple pie fruitcake wafer fruitcake. Tart gummies cake.
  </div>
  <label for="chkbx1" class="lbl"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for.  Was trying a different way with div and couldn't get it to work.  The content: was the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: You welcome and I'm glad it helped, the benefit of doing it with a `checkbox` is to make use of the `check` event, as some times we can make use of `:target` for `<a>` tags, and `:checked` for `radio` button but in the later case it works if we have more than one option, checkboxes could be triggered on or off even if we have on checkbox,, enjoy coding